# can this sorting algorithm be considered as a variation of bubble sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

can this approach be considered a variation of bubble sort? if not then what are the key differences and what is the efficiency comparison between this approach and bubble sort?

```
def bubble_sort(arr):

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr)-i):
            if arr[i] > arr[j+i]:
                arr[i], arr[j+i] = arr[j+i], arr[i]
    return arr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [21,4,1,3,9,20,25,6,21,14]
    print(bubble_sort(arr))
```

**output**: [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 20, 21, 21, 25]

Comment: That's as basic as possible for a bubble sort implementation.

Comment: One of the inefficiencies in your code is that `j` starts at 0. So the code checks `if arr[i] > arr[0+i]`, which is obviously never true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has implemented the algorithm [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) rather than [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Though they are somewhat similar: they are both based on element swapping.

For selection sort, the algorithm's key though is to find the minimal or maximum element and swap at last:

> The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending
> on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging
> (swapping) it with the leftmost unsorted element (putting it in sorted
> order), and moving the sublist boundaries one element to the right.

And your code can be improved to avoid unnecessary swaping:

```py
import random

def my_sort(arr):

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(len(arr)-i):
            if arr[min_idx] > arr[j+i]:
                min_idx = j + i
        arr[i],arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
    return arr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(360):
        i = i + 1
        r = random.choices(range(i * 10), k=i)   # Get list of numbers
        r1 = r.copy()
        assert my_sort(r) == sorted(r1)
```